# MongoDB can't update a value by specific ID in Next JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, next.js, fetch

I'm trying to update a "title" of a specific document found by "_id" in a collection.

In Next.JS API folder I'm using handler below:

```
export default async function handler(req: any, res: any) {

  try {
    const session = await getSession(req, res);
    const user = session?.user;
    const client = await clientPromise;
    const db = client.db("dbName");

    const { chatId, title } = req.body;

    const chat = await db.collection("collectionName").findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        _id: new ObjectId(chatId),
        userId: user?.sub,
      },
      {
        $set: {
          title: title,
        },
      },
      {
        returnDocument: "after",
      }
    );

    res.status(200).json({
      ...chat,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "An error occured adding message to a chat" });
  }
}
```

My single document from a collection looks like this :

```
{
   _id: ObjectId(string),
   userId: string,
   messages: Array,
   title: string
}
```

I'm fetching with a given function, but it always returns an empty object:

```
  const fetchAndUpdateTitle = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`/api/database/updateTitle`, {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify({ chatId: chatId, title: finalTitle }),
    });
    const json = await response.json();
    console.log("from title: ", json);

  };
```

Comment: Are you sure `user?.sub` has some value?